# Display Good-looking Math Formula in Android

Tags: javascript, android, math, mathjax, jqmath

It is sad to see that science and math is never given enough attention in Android platform. Maybe this is an easy problem, but I'm a total *dude* in javascript so I'm struggling to understand how to solve this problem.

What I want to do is simple: **I just need to use render mathematic equation. It can be MathJax or JqMath or anything that is small and fast. If I have to do it in a webview, how can I show plain text in paragraph and formatted equation within the same webview?**

(anyone comes out with other methods which obviously works, I'll consider that as solution also)

WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR:

I started with using MathJax to put formula into webview (*I don't know if there is any successful jqMath use case out there? Anyone care to share their experience?*) I can reproduce all the functionalities just like that of the standalone [MathJax App](http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498). In that app, a user keys in a string into EditText field and MathJax will render the formula in Latex once user presses a button to confirm.

I don't need user to confirm. I thought this should be easier because there is no user-interaction, but somehow the equation never gets displayed. I know I must be missing something because the codes in the standalone MathJax is meant for user input. Which part of the code should I modify to directly render an equation from a string, say, \sqrt{b^2-4ac} ?  Here is the initial header for webview:

```
WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                        +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ showMathMenu: false, "
                        +"jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                        +"extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], " 
                        +"TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                        +"'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
                        +"});</script>"
                        +"<script type='text/javascript' "
                        +"src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                        +"></script><span id='math'></span>","text/html","utf-8","");
```

And here is how the original webview loads when user presses a button after input to edittext:

```
WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                  +doubleEscapeTeX(e.getText().toString())
                  +"\\\\]';");
w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");

private static String doubleEscapeTeX(String s) {
    String t="";
    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '\'') t += '\\';
        if (s.charAt(i) != '\n') t += s.charAt(i);
        if (s.charAt(i) == '\\') t += "\\";
    }
    return t;
}
```

I attempted to replace with a hard-coded string

```
w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                  +doubleEscapeTeX("sample string")
                  +"\\\\]';");
```

but it doesn't work, the text `"sample string"` won't even show up in the webview.

**[SOLUTION] see Joe's Answer**

To elaborate on his answer, this is an example on how to set a sentence in plain text and then display a formatted equation in display form (all in a single webview):

Replace the last line above at

```
+"></script><span id='math'></span>","text/html","utf-8","");
```

with

```
+"></script><span id='text'>This is plain text.</span> <span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Then call

```
w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (!url.startsWith("http://bar"))
            return;
        w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                    +doubleEscapeTeX("\\sqrt{b^2-4ac}") + "\\\\]';");
        w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
    }
});
```

This will set a string *This is plain text* in normal font and center-display the formula [image: foo+bar] in webview.

**EDIT (Android 4.4 issue)**

Starting with Android KitKat, you have to replace all the lines `loadUrl(...)` with `evaluateJavascript(...)`. But this is only available for KitKat (API 19 or above), so you need to do an SDK version check first. For example:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
} else {
    w.evaluateJavascript("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);",null);
}
```

**UPDATE (AS OF MATHJAX 2.5)**

Because there are folders changes, previous code won't work on latest version of MathJax. Besides, the recommended way to minimalize the size of local MathJax is now using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started). The template to reduce size of MathJax can be found [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner).

Assuming you have successfully reduced the size of MathJax, and assuming output of HTML-CSS, here is a simple version that can load MathJax:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    String Url = "</style>"
                 + "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                 + "  MathJax.Hub.Config({" + "    showMathMenu: false,"
                 + "             jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS', 'output/CommonHTML'],"
                 + "      extensions: ['tex2jax.js','MathMenu.js','MathZoom.js', 'CHTML-preview.js'],"
                 + "         tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ['$','$'] ], processEscapes: true },"
                 + "             TeX: {" + "               extensions:['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                 + "                           'noUndefined.js']" + "             }"
                 + "  });"
                 + "</script>"
                 + "<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'>"
                 + "</script>"
                 + "<p style=\"line-height:1.5; padding: 16 16\" align=\"justify\">"
                 + "<span >";

    // Demo display equation
    url += "This is a display equation: $$P=\frac{F}{A}$$";

    url += "This is also an identical display equation with different format:\\[P=\\frac{F}{A}\\]";

    // equations aligned at equal sign
    url += "You can also put aligned equations just like Latex:";
    String align = "\\begin{aligned}"
                + "F\\; &= P \\times A \\\\ "
                + "&= 4000 \\times 0.2\\\\"
                + "&= 800\\; \\text{N}\\end{aligned}"; 
    url += align;

    url += "This is an inline equation \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}.";

    // Finally, must enclose the brackets
    url += "</span></p>";

    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", url, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (!url.startsWith("http://bar")) return;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                view.loadUrl(JAVASCRIPT);
            } else {
                view.evaluateJavascript(JAVASCRIPT, null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Unlike Joes's answer, there is no need to separate text or math types, MathJax will just format them accordingly.

However, it appears that there is a bug that webview in KitKat devices cannot render capital letter "A". Anyone who knows a way is welcome to provide a workaround for this.

Comment: This doesn't work on android 4.4. Do you have any solution for that ?

Comment: See new edit in post.

Comment: for the result you get is it possible to edit it like : http://mathquill.com/ ? @Neoh

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it seems the issue is due to the MathJax library has not completed loading (from the `loadDataWithBaseURL()` call) when you call the additional `loadUrl()`s to display the formula. The simplest fix is to wait for the `onPageFinished()` callback to make the call.

For example, the following code seems to work fine on mine:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>" 
            + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
            + "showMathMenu: false, " 
            + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " 
            + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], "
            + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js'," 
            + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
            + "});</script>" 
            + "<script type='text/javascript' " 
            + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
            + "></script><span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (!url.startsWith("http://bar")) return;
            w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                    + doubleEscapeTeX("sample string") + "\\\\]';");
            w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**: To accommodate additional output in the WebView, I would suggest adding HTML elements to the initial `loadDataWithBaseURL()` call. So for the example above, instead of this line at the end:

```
            + "></script><span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

We can do something like the following:

```
            + "></script><span id='text'>Formula:</span>"
            + "<span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Additionally, if you need to update that part interactively afterward, you can use the same mechanism that we used for the "math" part, something like:

```
            w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('text').innerHTML='"
                    + newText + "';");
```

You can also use other HTML elements (instead of the `<span>` that we use above) if you want to have specific styling/formatting.

Comment: This is one possible solution. I'll try that out and report back.

Comment: It shows. One last question: how do you put plain text into the same webview? For example, a sentence in default font, followed by formatted equation (inline or display)?

Comment: Glad to help :) I updated my answer to add some suggestions on how to add the text output.

Comment: After I set the plain text, w.loadUrl() really do overwrite the text and only shows the formula as a result. I'm a little confused as to how to append some text before or after the formula? Thanks!

Comment: I got the wrong idea about how the <span> tag works. Now I can make the plain text and formula to show at the webview. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks this is awesome solution and working well below android 4.4. After android 4.4 I am getting error ""Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)". See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582282/uncaught-referenceerror-while-loading-asset-file-on-android-4-4

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using javascript and javascript libraries to render the LaTeX client-side, why not do the following?

1. Write a server-side function that takes some LaTeX string and produces an image file. You can do this with the "out of the box" standard LaTeX command line tool. *(It seems like this is something you're capable of doing, and that the problem is in getting the rendering to take place client-side.)*
2. Create an endpoint on your web site/service that looks like the following:
   `GET /latex?f={image format}&s={latex string}`
3. On your web pages, use a simple HTML `<img/>` tag to render your LaTeX. For example:
   `<img src="/latex?f=jpeg&s=f%40x%41%61x%942"/>`
   will render the `f(x)=x^2` equation as a JPEG.
4. (optional) Create a simple server-side cache for `(f,s)` pairs so that you only render a particular LaTeX string on the first request ever made for that particular string (by any client). As a first prototype, you could just have a server directory in which you have files named `{hash(s)}.{f}`, where `hash` is just some hash function like `SHA1`.

This relieves you from trying to make everything work client-side with javascript. And, I would argue (although some may disagree), that this is a lot cleaner. All you're sending to the client is:

1. the HTML `<img/>` tag
2. the actual image contents when the browser resolves the `src` attribute

Very lightweight and fast!

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I need an offline solution. I'm using webview only because mathjax requires it. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @Neoh Oh okay - I maybe should have guessed that from the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

The "capital A" problem is a konwn bug of MathJax on Android WebView. You can replace the font files with [tweaked font files](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathjax-users/j0ohai-plEM/_if2-RBBdNUJ). The fix will work when using HTML-CSS output with TeX-fonts. Besides MathJax, you can try [KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX), which is less beautiful but faster.

Actually I've packed them both into an Android custom view, have a look on [`MathView`](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView).

Comment: Thanks @kexanie for the library. It really helped in rendering latex code. I've hit a issue with the MathView not resizing (I understand its an inherent issue with webview because of this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18726 ).  Is there any workaround you suggest for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I think I have a better solution than Joe's.
The original question asked:

> how can I show plain text in paragraph and a formatted equation within
>   the same webview?

In the original example we had:

```
w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                  +doubleEscapeTeX("sample string")
                  +"\\\\]';");
```

Do you notice the `\\\\[` and `\\\\]`? Those four backslashes are interpreted by LaTeX as only one, and `\[` and `\]` in LaTeX [is a shorthand for](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments) `\begin{equation}... \end{equation}` which produces a block of displayed mathematics. If we want a paragraph of text with some equations within the paragraph we need to get rid of the `\\\\[` and  use the LaTeX command `\(` and `\)`. The code for an example with paragraph mathematics and displayed mathematics would be:

```
w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='"
   +doubleEscapeTeX(
           "This is a second degree equation \\( \\small ax^2+bx+c=0\\) and its "
          +"roots are \\[x=\\frac{-b\\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}. \\]"
    )+"';");
```

The WebView becomes:
[image]
Notes:

- We only need two backslashes instead of four, this is because we are inside `doubleEscapeTeX()` and this function duplicates the backslashes.
- Also the text outside the math environments is rendered with HTML (inside the `<span id='math'>` tag).
- The LaTeX font is bigger that the html font, so adding a `\\small` in each math environment will make them roughly the same size. Here I added the `\\small` command only to the first equation to show the difference.

Answer (score 0):

jqMath is a JavaScript library like MathJax, but **much smaller, simpler, and faster.** If you don't need all of LaTeX, you might like it. It should work fine on Android.

It is just a suggestion, I have no idea what errors or advantages you might have if you use MathJax.

MathJax is much bigger and more complicated than jqMath, and **roughly 5 times slower**.

Working JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sinhayash/gWWB5/1/

For `\sqrt{b^2-4ac}` you can have this code: `√(b^2-4ac)`

You can easily use string handling in javascript to convert strings to the jqMath format and easily display it

Comment: I tried to use Jqmath some time ago but I couldn't make it work. As I said I don't have knowledge about javascript, what sounds like piece of cake to you is actually a barrier that newbies like us can't overcome. Specifically I never see an example of jqmath code that is being used in Android. That's why I cannot accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use math formula in android using below code.

```
public void setView(String data,WebView w){
    WebSettings webSettings = w.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String path="file:///android_asset/v/";
    String js="<html><head>"
       + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='file:///android_asset/v/jqmath.css'>"
       + "<script src = 'file:///android_asset/v/jquery-3.0.0.min.js'></script>"
       + "<script src = 'file:///android_asset/v/jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js'></script>"
       + "<script src = 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>"
       + "</head><body>"
       + "<script>var s ='"+data+"';M.parseMath(s);document.write(s);</script> </body>";
    w.loadDataWithBaseURL("", js, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
}
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.