# How to show math formula in android using eclipse

Tags: android, mathjax

I want to show a math formula in my android app.for that i found mathjax library and use it but the problem is it works so slow to showing a formula especially the first time and more time it doesn't show anything in webview.
**in my app the formula is written by the user and the webview must be updated alternatively and i cant use libs which work with cloud computing.**
I want to know if there is a faster library to show math formulas and  example projects maybe.
Or if there is a way for fixing the problem with MathJax.
and i see these links but i don't get my expectations.
[MathML and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java/1792641)
[Display Good-looking Math Formula in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029780/display-good-looking-math-formula-in-android)