# Struggle with character "\" trying to display math formulas with mathjax

Tags: java, android, math, formula, mathjax

I'm trying to display a math formula written in LaTex in a webview, but i'm struggling with the character "\": I can't write "\" because is error, but if I use "\\" the app fails in rendering the formula.

```
url += "This is a display equation: $$P=\frac{F}{A}$$";

url += "This is also an identical display equation with different format:\\[P=\\frac{F}{A}\\]";
```

I'm using this question as a model:  [Display Good-looking Math Formula in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029780/display-good-looking-math-formula-in-android)

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the ascii value or &bsol;

Comment: Did you try `\\(` and `\\)` instead of `\\[` and `\\]` like one of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029780/display-good-looking-math-formula-in-android suggests?

Comment: Did you try: 
`url += "This is also an identical display equation with different format:"+"\\"+"[P="+"\\"+"frac{F}{A}"+"\\"+"]";`

Comment: I tried your solutions, but it still give me rendering error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who has my own problem... I recently discoverd that there is a easier way to display math formulas with MathView.
If anyone is interested: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView/blob/master/README.md